# Is continuous function space with standard inner product on $\big[0,\frac{1}{2}\big]$ not complete?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, inner-products

I think Fourier approximation on step function is one example of incompleteness, is it true? Or could you suggest any intuitive examples for incompleteness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not complete. Take a function $f(x)=1$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. You can show that $f(x)$ can be well approximated by elements in $C[0,1]$ but $f$ is not in $C[0,1]$. The closure of $C[0,1]$ is actually what's called $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for easy example! Maybe $f(x) = (nx)^{2}$ if $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n^2})$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in [\frac{1}{n^{2}},1]$ is example for yours since it's side limit on $x=\frac{1}{n^2}$ is exist and equal to 0, which is function's value.

Comment: I would write 'completion' rather than 'closure'. As an explicit example, take $f_n(x) = (2x)^n$ on $[0 , {1 \over 2}]$, then the sequence is Cauchy, but $f_n(x) \to 1_{\{{1 \over 2}\}}(x)$, which is not continuous.